# eclipse CDT build in docker is not indexing

Tags: eclipse, docker, eclipse-cdt, indexer

i have a CDT project in eclipse. i created a new docker image and added a new library and header files to it (libmodbus).
When compiling it, everything works smoothly, however when editing it's marking all headers that are to come from the docker as missing. reindexing doesn't work. Making the project over and over doesn't work as well, eclipse is not indexing the files in the docker. what can be done to fix it ? the settings are NOT in the indexer as i checked them and they seem to be ok.

Any pin points ?

Answer (score -1):

like always thank you for nothing stackvoerflow members...

could not get it to work so i tried to update the plugin, hopeful that it will be a known bug. I don't know because many plugins were updated and the project did not work anymore, i had to start all over creating the CDT managed project from scratch.
Of course the indexer now works, probably it would have worked if i re-created the project in the old eclipse.
Let's just say that in c-lion it would not happen, and i have a hunch if i'll start of with visualstudio code it will probably be better too.